# Calculating volume of revolving function around x then y-axes

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given:
$f(x)=(x^2)+1$,

$x=1$ & $x=2$

Find volume of enclosed revolved around x-axis

$\int_1^2 \pi (x^2 + 1)^2 dx = \pi \int_1^2 (x^2 + 1)^2 dx$

$= \pi \int_1^2 (x^4 +2x^2 +1) dx = [\pi(\frac{x^5}{5} + \frac{2x^3}{3}+x)]|_1^2$

$=\frac{178\pi}{15}$

Revolve same section of around y-axis:
$y=x^2+1$

Solving for x:

$x = \sqrt{y-1}$

Finding bounds:

$1=\sqrt{y-1}, 2=\sqrt{y-1}$

$y=2, y=5$ respectively

For some reason I think I'm messing up somewhere around this point, I could be wrong though:

$\int_2^5 \pi (\sqrt{y-1})^2dy = ... = \frac{15\pi}{2}$

I don't think this integral represents what I'm trying to do here.

I know that the part around the x-axis is correct but why isn't the y-axis portion? Someone mind telling me where I went wrong?

Comment: You should be using shells instead of disks when you rotate around the $y$ axis. Can you see why?

Comment: No, I really don't. What's the issue? We've been taught to use discs/washers primarily, almost exclusively... actually I don't think we've even been shown shells yet.

Comment: You are rotating the same area around the $y$ axis so look at the shape of the volume. There is a hole in the center. Is the correct answer $\frac{21\pi}{2}?$ When I said shells, I meant washers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to rotate the area bound by the $x$ axis, the curve $y=x^2+1$ and the lines $x=1$ and $x=2$ about the $y$ axis. Using the method of shells, I get $$\int_1^2 2\pi xydx=2\pi\int_1^2 x(x^2+1)dx=2\pi\int_1^2(x^3+x)dx$$

When I evaluate this I get $\frac{21\pi}{2}$

Comment: Not sure that it is correct, at least per the washer method. I understood it as the following using that method:

$\pi \int _2^5 (outer radius)^2-(inner radius)^2 dy$

$= \pi \int _2^5 (2)^2-(\sqrt{y-1})^2 dy$

$= \frac{22\pi}{3}$ ?

Comment: @defcon5 I updated this to use the correct terminology. I also clarified which volume I was calculating. I believe your integral is calculating the volume obtained by rotating the area bound by $y=x^2+1$ and the lines $x=2$, $y=2$ and $y=5$ around the $y$ axis. Is that correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct. However, we haven't been taught the shell method. It can be solved using the washer method, I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong. I think that it has to do with the fact that there is two inner radii that I need to address, which I did not in my previous comment

Comment: $\pi(\int_2^5 2^2 - \sqrt{y-1}^2dy + \int_0^2 2^2 - 1^2 dy )$ is what I was looking for